# How do you clone a BufferedImage

Tags: java, copy, clone, bufferedimage

I have an object which has many bufferedimages in it, I want to create a new object copying all the bufferedimages into the new object, but these new images may be altered and i don't want the original object images to be altered by altering the new objects images.

is that clear?

Is this possible to do and can anyone suggest a good way to do it please?
I have thought of getSubImage but read somewhere that any changes to the subimage are relected back to the parent image.

I just want to be able to get a fresh entirely separate copy or clone of a BufferedImage

Comment: can't you call the `clone()` method? Or have I missed something? I don't know a great deal about the `BufferedImage` class

Comment: clone only provides a shallow copy so it would contain the references to the buffered images; not copies of them.

Comment: @NoelM, UltimateGobblement: `BufferedImage` does not implement `Cloneable` and the `clone()` method has protected access.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Something like this?

```
static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi) {
 ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
 boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
 WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(null);
 return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
}
```

Comment: I'm also borrowing this in my program =)

Comment: have issue with this method on copying subimage

Comment: While this works under most circumstances, it doesn't work properly when that BufferedImage has been cropped(it returns the whole image before it was cropped). A simple fix to this is to change that last line to:

Comment: return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null).getSubimage(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

Comment: copyData(null) does not always work because it may work on a parent raster (ie. when the image is a sub image), see my modified answer

Comment: @f1wade @BlackSheep @HaydenStudios @user1050755 Is there a way to alter the size of the `BufferedImage` after cloning it?

Comment: Should have a null check on bi (e.g. if you're using this in a copy constructor) shouldn't there?

Answer (score 58):

I do this:

```
public static BufferedImage copyImage(BufferedImage source){
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), source.getType());
    Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return b;
}
```

It works fairly well and it is simple to use.

Comment: This looks pretty simple. Why this is n't the best answer? Is there a flaw that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @WVrock It doesn't work if the image type is 0 (custom)

Comment: replace Graphics g = b.getGraphics(); by 

    Graphics2D g = b.createGraphics(); 

and it is perfect

Comment: I think this is the cleanest answer. Although is there any performance difference between this and the accepted answer? I feel like negligible if any no? Could this be faster purely cause object creation is optimized in the jvm. Also using openjdk 11. If anyone can answer that question.

Answer (score 27):

The previously mentioned procedure fails when applied to sub images. Here is a more complete solution:

```
public static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi) {
    ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(bi.getRaster().createCompatibleWritableRaster());
    return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting an offset error trying to clone a subimage. This version is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use the `Graphics2D` class to draw the image onto a new blank image. This doesn't really clone the image, but it results in a copy of the image being produced.

```
public static final BufferedImage clone(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferedImage clone = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), image.getType());
    Graphics2D g2d = clone.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return clone;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that this question is pretty old, but for future visitors, here's the solution I'd use:

```
Image oldImage = getImage();
Image newImage = oldImage.getScaledInstance(oldImage.getWidth(null), oldImage.getHeight(null), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

Please correct me if changing the just obtained `newImage` also affects the original image in any way.
--> [Javadoc for getScaledInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)
--> [Javadoc for SCALE_DEFAULT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#SCALE_DEFAULT) (the other constants are listed just below that one)

Comment: I think that would not actually copy the image,ie if you changed the original the scaled willalso change, but its been a while so ill let someone else say for sure.

Comment: This does actually copy the image, in that changes to the original will not change the copy. This answer is short and concise and isn't even limited to BufferedImages. The only issue is that it returns `Image`, not `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 2):

Class BufferedImage does not implement the Cloneable interface. Thus the clone method is not overriden. Here's an alternative for a deep copy technique:
[Java Tip 76: An alternative to the deep copy technique](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip76.html)

Comment: BufferedImage is not serializable, which makes this alternative hard to use ..

Answer (score 1):

The following solution using arraycopy is about **3-4 times faster** than the accepted answer:

```
public static BufferedImage copyImage(BufferedImage source){
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), source.getType());
    byte[] sourceData = ((DataBufferByte)source.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    byte[] biData = ((DataBufferByte)bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(sourceData, 0, biData, 0, sourceData.length);
    return bi;
}
```

By the way, the answers using Graphics2D provide similarly good results.

Comment: May fail: ```java
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0
 at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:501)
```

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior which image format, which Java version and which operating system are you using? There are some reported issues with PNG and TIFF. A hack exists where in case the image type is 0 it is manually set to 5...

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior try to replace "source.getType()" with "source.getType()==0?5:source.getType()"

Comment: This really is much faster. Unfortunately it doesn't scale well when the array gets large. I wonder if we could multi-thread this to speed it up...

Comment: Yeah it seems like the bottleneck isn't the CPU, no help from MT.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I wrote many years ago for JFreeChart.

It will also copy any Properties which may be present in the BufferedImage.

I believe it was tested with all known Colour Models (Image Types).

Whether it will work with `Image Type 0` discussed by @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior I don't know.
**But:** Image Type 0 is invalid & should not occur.

```
/**
 * Copied from
 * <a href=https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/util/PaintAlpha.java>JFreeChart PaintAlpha</a>
 * 
 * @param   srcImage
 * @return  
 */
public static BufferedImage cloneImage(final BufferedImage srcImage) {

    final WritableRaster srcRaster = srcImage.getRaster();
    final WritableRaster dstRaster = srcRaster.createCompatibleWritableRaster();
    /*
     * This is the code that actually COPIES the pixels...
     */
    dstRaster.setRect(srcRaster);
    /*
     * Images hardly ever have Properties, but we copy them anyway...
     */
    final String[]                  propNames = srcImage.getPropertyNames();
    final Hashtable<String, Object> props;

    if (propNames == null) {
        props     =  null;
    } else {
        props     =  new Hashtable<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < propNames.length; i++) {
            props.put(propNames[i], srcImage.getProperty(propNames[i]));
        }
    }
    /*
     * That's it folks! Return the new clone...
     */
    return new BufferedImage(srcImage.getColorModel(), dstRaster, srcImage.isAlphaPremultiplied(), props);
}
```

Comment: Type 0 (TYPE_CUSTOM) isn't invalid, and it can definitely occur in the real world (based on having encountered them there). It just means that it has a custom definition for how it is laid out in memory. That said, they tend to be a pain in the rear to deal with and it is probably entirely fine to simply say "this wont' work for a type 0, if you have that you probably need to be looking at pulling it into one of the standard types first anyway" (a _lot_ of things don't work on TYPE_CUSTOM).

Answer (score 0):

I have made this solution using two functions it works on every possible image, even image by camcorder of laptop, I was facing problem that after croping image through camera it was not working but this solution will work

```
static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi) 
{
    try
    {
        ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
        boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
        WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(bi.getRaster().createCompatibleWritableRaster());
        return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
    try{
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), bi.getType());
        Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return b;
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        
        
        
    }
    
    return null;
}
```