# How to clone Image?

Tags: java, performance, image, clone, copying

I have an Image. I need to make a exactly copy of it and save it to BufferedImage, but there is no Image.clone(). The thing should be inside a calculating loop and so it should be really fast, no pixel-by-pixel copying. What's the best in perfomance method to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514158/how-do-you-clone-a-bufferedimage

Comment: It copies Image pixel-by-pixel (just copies the raster data). Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: If you want a deep copy, there is no other way I know about. And why do you want to clone it every loop iteration?

Comment: Actually I need to make a lot of image copies which is rotated by 1 degree, so I need to copy basic image and perform some operations on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can draw to a buffered image, so make a blank **bufferedImage**, create a graphics context from it, and draw your original image to it.

```
BufferedImage copyOfImage = 
   new BufferedImage(widthOfImage, heightOfImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = copyOfImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: That would lose transparency.  If in doubt, use `TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

Comment: Hm... This looks faster for me.

Comment: Always remember to `dispose()` the `Graphics` object after use!

Answer (score 1):

There is another way:

```
BufferedImage copyOfImage = image.getSubimage(0, 0, image.getWidth, image.getHeight);
```

Comment: No, this won't work, as `copyOfImage` and `image` will share backing buffers (it will be a shallow copy). Edits made to one, will be reflected in the other.

Answer (score 0):

`Image clone = original.getScaledInstance(original.getWidth(), -1, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);`

This might not be very pretty, but `getScaledInstance` returns, as the name suggests, an instance of your original `Image` object. Usually only used for resizing. `-1` tells the method to keep the aspect ratio as it is

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that returns the subimage of the image you want to clone.

Such as:

```
public static BufferedImage clone(BufferedImage img)
{
  return img.getSubimage(img.getMinX(), img.getMinY(), img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
}
```