# How are Task's objects in ExecutorService handled?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to write in parallel an image which gets modified each iteration of a loop. The code looks like:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
{
            pool.execute(() -> {
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "JPG", fileName + i);
            });
            //Operations on the image...
}
```

The problem is that the image gets written just at its **initial state** *(i=array.length)* and at its **final** *(i=1)*, but it actually writes the numbers of files it should *(array.length times)*.
So my question is, do I have to **synchronize** something on the image I'm writing?
Aren't the **objects state snapshotted and saved in memory** once the Task gets into the queue? Or do tasks get the state of the object at the **time of their actual execution?**

Comment: Why the `if(i % delay == 0)`?

Comment: You’ve not explained `array`, nor other details. Voting to close for lack of detail.

Comment: I removed the `i % delay` to avoid any confusion. It's not important for the question to know which are the operations and how many times the loop get executed. @talex actually answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task get state on moment of execution.

There is no straightforward way to get snapshot of object in java.

Comment: Thanks @talex. Do you know if there's a Runnable implementation which gets the state of the object at the moment of it's scheduling?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the image before each `Runnable` has an opportunity to save the state of the image at the time you set up the sub-task. To avoid this problem you could make a copy of the image before setting up each runnable as follows:

```
BufferedImage imageCopy = copyImage(bufferedImage);
pool.execute(() -> {
    ImageIO.write(imageCopy, "JPG", fileName + i);
});
```

See these answers for possible implementations of `copyImage(BufferedImage)` and conditions / restrictions:
[Clone image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864275/how-to-clone-image) [How to clone image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514158/how-do-you-clone-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: It wasn't actually this the problem, but your answer helped me figuring out how to fix the problem i had. Upvote.