# How to copy an Image/BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, graphics, copy, bufferedimage

I have a `BufferedImage`. I want to do two copy of it, to write some things with their Graphics. But, if I *write* something on one, it will do the same on all the other copy, so I tried to do `image.getSubImage(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());`, but it doesn't change anything.

I don't know what to do, it would be super to help me.

Comment: You should show us your code, it is probably a quick fix

Comment: This is an entire library, so it contains so many classes, sinclair's solution works ! I just wait because i can't valid the solution now.

Comment: `image.getSubImage(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()` just returns image, not a clone.

Comment: @TheShark34 you didn't need to link your whole project.... just the relevant lines would have been ok

Comment: @TheShark34 sinclair does not provide a solution, he (assumption) only provides an existing question with answer which apparently answers yours. In other words: this is a duplicate question. As such I voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @MCMastery Oh ok, i can't upvote it because i don't have enough reputation, and the question that he given had a working solution, and the lines was using so much methods and things, so this is why i didn't give the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the top answer of this question and see if it fits your situation:

[How do you clone a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514158/how-do-you-clone-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: Omg it works ! I don't know why i didn't found this solution, thanks you so much ! I just need to wait a little to accept the answer, but thanks you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Please, try something like this:

```
ColorModel model = image.getColorModel();
WritableRaster raster = image.copyData(null);
BufferedImage clone = new BufferedImage(model, raster, model.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```