# Filtering rgb image works only one time in java

Tags: java, image, filter, rgb

I want to filter my `BufferedImage` in java.
Currently, I have this piece of code:

```
private void changeRGB(BufferedImage image, int colour) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int newColor = 0;

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
      for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
          Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y));

          int red = color.getRed();
          int green = color.getGreen();
          int blue = color.getBlue();

          if (colour == 1) {
              newColor = new Color(red, 0, 0).getRGB();
          } else if (colour == 2) {
              newColor = new Color(0, green, 0).getRGB();
          } else if (colour == 3) {
              newColor = new Color(0, 0, blue).getRGB();
          }

          image.setRGB(x, y, newColor);
      }
    }
    icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    this.lblFilteredImage.setIcon(icon);
}
```

and if I press e.g. the red, green or blue button I do it this way:

`choice = 2; changeRGB(img, choice);`

This code works **one** time and if I press one of these buttons the 2nd time it doesn't work anymore

Comment: `color` and `colour` variables in the same scope? You should definetly change one of those variable names... Furthermore if applied more than once to the same image, the image either does not change, since you extract the same channel you already extracted or the image becomes black, since you extract a color that was set to 0 before...

Comment: Ok but how can I solve that issue so the image doesn't get black?

Comment: Use 2 Images, one with the source and the other with the filtered data. Applying different filters does not make sense in with those filters; so I guess you want to apply only one of these filters at once.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are modifying the "source" image stored in the BufferedImage, use a new BufferedImage to store the result and thus avoid destroying your source image.

you can try it this way, so the "source" image is left unaltered.

```
private void changeRGB(BufferedImage image,int colour)
{
    int width=image.getWidth();
    int height=image.getHeight();
    int newColor=0;
    BufferedImage tempBuffer=new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getType());
    for(int y=0;y<height;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<width;x++)
        {
            Color color=new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

            int red=color.getRed();
            int green=color.getGreen();
            int blue=color.getBlue();

            if(colour==1)
            {
                newColor=new Color(red, 0, 0).getRGB();
            }
            else if(colour==2)
            {
                newColor=new Color(0, green, 0).getRGB();
            }
            else if(colour==3)
            {
                newColor=new Color(0, 0, blue).getRGB();
            }

            tempBuffer.setRGB(x, y, newColor);
        }
    }
    icon=new ImageIcon(tempBuffer);
    this.lblFilteredImage.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Alex is right. `BufferedImage` is mutable, so `changeRGB` changes the "original" `BufferedImage`.

[Clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514158/how-do-you-clone-a-bufferedimage) the `BufferedImage` and process the clone.

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated