# How to copy image in java using bufferedreader/writer

Tags: java, java-io

```
    File file = new File("download.png");
    File newfile = new File("D:\\Java.png");
    BufferedReader br=null;
    BufferedWriter bw=null;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newfile);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = br.read(buf)) > 0) {
            bw.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        bw.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Whats wrong with this code. Is it possible with BufferedReader and Writer Class??
I know how to to make copy of image using InputStream and OutputStream, So don't paste solution using that!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you clone a BufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514158/how-do-you-clone-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: The short answer is that you can't.  Reader and Writer APIs are for text, and images are not text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Whats wrong with this code.

You're using text-based classes for binary data.

> Is it possible with BufferedReader and Writer Class?

Not while you're dealing with binary data, no.

> I know how to to make copy of image using InputStream and OutputStream, So don't paste solution using that!

That's the solution you should use, because those are the classes designed for binary data.

Fundamentally, using `Reader` or `Writer` for non-text data is broken, and asking for trouble. If you open up the file in a text editor and don't see text, it's not a text file... (Alternatively, it could be a text file that you're using the wrong encoding for, but things like images and sound aren't naturally text.)

Comment: Also would like to ask if video is also read in binary form(binary data)??

Comment: @RajatGupta: Yes, absolutely. What text would you expect to see if you opened it up in Notepad?

Answer (score -1):

Use `javax.imageio.ImageIO` utility class, which has lots of utility method related to images processing.

```
try{
    File imagefile = new File("download.png");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imagefile);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("D:\\Java.png"));
    .....
}
```

Comment: That will change the image.  It’s better to copy the bytes instead of involving ImageIO.  Also, it keeps the entire image in memory, which means it won’t work with very large images.