# How can I deep copy 3D array of Objects with for loops in Java?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, nested-loops, deep-copy

I've created an number of BufferedImage Objects and stored them in an 3D array.
To shift my objects through the array I need to create a deep copy of the complete 3D array and after.. only after I can change the values of my copied array to return it.

When I create the first two objects (`new BufferedImage [ temp1.length ][ ][ ]` and `new BufferedImage [ temp1[ i ].length ][ ]`) arrays to iterate through them, the storage ID's are completely different than the Array ID's that I copied from..

So far so good...

(checked it using Debug mode)

The issue is that after my final new array object loop I do not know how to copy the collected int value ***k***.

If I set **temp 2** [ **i** ][ **j** ][ **k** ]= **temp1**[ **i** ][ **j** ][ **k** ].. the code is accepted but only refers to the stored ID location (shallow copy), it does not create a new one. (In debug mode  I can see the ID change to the same ID after instantiating ***k***..

When I run the code, many locations are set as a new object... but this issue causes multiple ***null*** values in my storage locations in run time.

Tried using the ***new*** keyword again, but it's not accepted because I've already have the number of arrays for the 3D arrays.

So.. how to properly write the last step of this code..

```
private BufferedImage [][][] mix(BufferedImage [][][] temp1) {
        
    BufferedImage [][][] temp2 = new BufferedImage [temp1.length][][];
        for(int i=0 ; i <temp1.length;i++) {
            
            
            temp2[i] = new BufferedImage [temp1[i].length][];
            for(int j=0;j<temp1[i].length;j++) {
                    
                temp2[i][j] = new BufferedImage[temp1[i][j].length];
                for(int k=0;k<temp1[i][j].length;k++) {
                    

                    // ** before this step..  the storage ID of temp2 = a different one (stil good)
                    
                    temp2[i][j][k] = temp1[i][j][k];
                    
                    // ** after this step..  the storage ID of temp2 = the same as temp 1 (not good)
                }
            }
        }
        return temp2;
}
```

Comment: You need to create a clone or copy of the `BufferedImage` at `temp1[i][j][k]`, not just copy the reference to it. Here's a previous discussion on [how to clone a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514158/how-do-you-clone-a-bufferedimage/26894825)

Comment: Thank you, SirRaffleBuffle. I'll look in to it for future reference.   Note; I started over and re-wrote the same code again .. now I do have another storage ID. I just don't understand what made the difference.